# Does Postgres's UPDATE query not work using the WITH statement and a schema identifier?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that uses the `WITH` statement to pass a value to two subsequent queries:

```
WITH rp AS (
            SELECT citydb_view.utn9_insert_ntw_feat_distrib_elem_pipe_round(
                id := NULL,
                gmlid := 'RoundPipeID_4e80843c-14a5-11e8-a94b-7824afca2075',
                gmlid_codespace := NULL,
                name := NULL,
                name_codespace := NULL,
                description := NULL,
                envelope := ST_Expand(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (426686.205399994 5450370.83199954 112.636166102332,426683.311999993 5450370.80149954 112.26385708932)', 26910), 0),
                creation_date := NULL,
                termination_date := NULL,
                relative_to_terrain := NULL,
                relative_to_water := NULL,
                last_modification_date := NULL,
                updating_person := NULL,
                reason_for_update := NULL,
                lineage := NULL,
                ntw_feature_parent_id := NULL,
                ntw_feature_root_id := NULL,
                class := NULL,
                function := 'distribution',
                usage := NULL,
                year_of_construction := '1978-01-01',
                status := 'inUse',
                location_quality := 'unknown',
                elevation_quality := 'estimated',
                cityobject_id := NULL,
                prot_element_id := NULL,
                geom := ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (426686.205399994 5450370.83199954 112.636166102332,426683.311999993 5450370.80149954 112.26385708932)', 26910),
                function_of_line := 'flowLine',
                is_gravity := NULL,
                ext_width := NULL,
                ext_width_unit := NULL,
                ext_height := NULL,
                ext_height_unit := NULL,
                ext_diameter := '150',
                ext_diameter_unit := NULL,
                int_diameter := NULL,
                int_diameter_unit := NULL,
                schema_name := 'citydb'
            ) AS fid
        ) /* This returns an integer id value */

        SELECT citydb_pkg.utn9_insert_network_to_network_feature(
            network_id := 2675,
            network_feature_id := rp.fid,
            schema_name := 'citydb'
        ) FROM rp,

        UPDATE
            citydb.utn9_feature_graph
        SET
            ntw_feature_id = (SELECT rp.fid FROM rp)
        WHERE
            id = 15938;
```

When executing, I get a syntax error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 51:             citydb.utn9_feature_graph
```

It is referring to this line:

But when I isolate this query and just substitute in an arbitrary integer for `(SELECT rp.fid FROM rp)`, it executes just fine.  Is the schema identifier messing it up somehow?

Postgres version is 9.6.6.

EDIT: Hang on, it looks like I got it to work:

```
WITH rp AS (
            SELECT citydb_view.utn9_insert_ntw_feat_distrib_elem_pipe_round(
                id := NULL,
                gmlid := 'RoundPipeID_4e80843c-14a5-11e8-a94b-7824afca2075',
                gmlid_codespace := NULL,
                name := NULL,
                name_codespace := NULL,
                description := NULL,
                envelope := ST_Expand(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (426686.205399994 5450370.83199954 112.636166102332,426683.311999993 5450370.80149954 112.26385708932)', 26910), 0),
                creation_date := NULL,
                termination_date := NULL,
                relative_to_terrain := NULL,
                relative_to_water := NULL,
                last_modification_date := NULL,
                updating_person := NULL,
                reason_for_update := NULL,
                lineage := NULL,
                ntw_feature_parent_id := NULL,
                ntw_feature_root_id := NULL,
                class := NULL,
                function := 'distribution',
                usage := NULL,
                year_of_construction := '1978-01-01',
                status := 'inUse',
                location_quality := 'unknown',
                elevation_quality := 'estimated',
                cityobject_id := NULL,
                prot_element_id := NULL,
                geom := ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (426686.205399994 5450370.83199954 112.636166102332,426683.311999993 5450370.80149954 112.26385708932)', 26910),
                function_of_line := 'flowLine',
                is_gravity := NULL,
                ext_width := NULL,
                ext_width_unit := NULL,
                ext_height := NULL,
                ext_height_unit := NULL,
                ext_diameter := '150',
                ext_diameter_unit := NULL,
                int_diameter := NULL,
                int_diameter_unit := NULL,
                schema_name := 'citydb'
            ) AS fid
        ),

x AS (
        SELECT citydb_pkg.utn9_insert_network_to_network_feature(
            network_id := 2675,
            network_feature_id := rp.fid,
            schema_name := 'citydb'
        ) FROM rp
)

UPDATE
            citydb.utn9_feature_graph
        SET
            ntw_feature_id = (SELECT rp.fid FROM rp)
        WHERE
            id = 15;
```

All I did was wrap the first query after the `WITH` in brackets and save it `AS` a variable `x`.  I don't really understand why is works though, could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

what you intend to do is possible:

```
with url AS ( SELECT 'https://stackoverflow.com' )
update communities set url = (SELECT * FROM url) where name = 'SO';
```

What is that select doing in there ?

```
    SELECT citydb_pkg.utn9_insert_network_to_network_feature(
        network_id := 2675,
        network_feature_id := rp.fid,
        schema_name := 'citydb'
    ) FROM rp,

    UPDATE
        citydb.utn9_feature_graph
    SET
```

Maybe try something like that:

```
      WITH rp AS (
        SELECT citydb_view.utn9_insert_ntw_feat_distrib_elem_pipe_round(
            id := NULL,
            gmlid := 'RoundPipeID_4e80843c-14a5-11e8-a94b-7824afca2075',
            gmlid_codespace := NULL,
            name := NULL,
            name_codespace := NULL,
            description := NULL,
            envelope := ST_Expand(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (426686.205399994 5450370.83199954 112.636166102332,426683.311999993 5450370.80149954 112.26385708932)', 26910), 0),
            creation_date := NULL,
            termination_date := NULL,
            relative_to_terrain := NULL,
            relative_to_water := NULL,
            last_modification_date := NULL,
            updating_person := NULL,
            reason_for_update := NULL,
            lineage := NULL,
            ntw_feature_parent_id := NULL,
            ntw_feature_root_id := NULL,
            class := NULL,
            function := 'distribution',
            usage := NULL,
            year_of_construction := '1978-01-01',
            status := 'inUse',
            location_quality := 'unknown',
            elevation_quality := 'estimated',
            cityobject_id := NULL,
            prot_element_id := NULL,
            geom := ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING Z (426686.205399994 5450370.83199954 112.636166102332,426683.311999993 5450370.80149954 112.26385708932)', 26910),
            function_of_line := 'flowLine',
            is_gravity := NULL,
            ext_width := NULL,
            ext_width_unit := NULL,
            ext_height := NULL,
            ext_height_unit := NULL,
            ext_diameter := '150',
            ext_diameter_unit := NULL,
            int_diameter := NULL,
            int_diameter_unit := NULL,
            schema_name := 'citydb'
        ) AS fid
    ) /* This returns an integer id value */

    UPDATE
        citydb.utn9_feature_graph
    SET
        ntw_feature_id = (SELECT rp.fid FROM rp)
    WHERE
        id = 15938
    RETURNING (
      SELECT citydb_pkg.utn9_insert_network_to_network_feature(
        network_id := 2675,
        network_feature_id := rp.fid,
        schema_name := 'citydb'
    ) FROM rp)
```

// UPDATE
As answer to your update, i think the clause you've used before is just not possible

```
SELECT * from something, update some set =.....
```